# Why does \psPrintValue not allow 2 \rput to work at the same time?

Tags: pstricks

For each compilation, only one of the 2 `\rput`s can be used. Attempting to activate both will produce a strange output which is only the first `\rput` can work.

```
\documentclass[border=0pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pstricks-add,pst-tools,times}



\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=true](6,6)
    \psforeach{\i}{1,3}
    {
        %\rput(\i,\i){\i}
        \rput(!\i\space 1 add dup){\psPrintValue{\i\space 1 add}}
    }
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Why does `\psPrintValue` not allow 2 `\rput`s to work at the same time?

**Edit:**
I am still  using TeXLive 2011.

The strange behavior above occurs only when I use `latex->dvips->ps2pdf` sequence. For `xelatex`, it works without problem.

Comment: is `\rput(!\i\space 1 add dup)` even legal? I only see \rput documented as taking coordinates as two tex expressions separated by comma?

Comment: well it seems to be I just didn't see it in the manual (well it's used once in the middle of a large code section on page 182:(  Presumably you have a real use case somewhere, because the examples using postscript arithmetic you've been posting could all be done more easily with tex arithmetic?

Comment: Actually it works for me (TL2012) if I uncomment the second one I get oh where can I put an image, I have to make it a answer?

Comment: What Kind of _strange_ output so you get?

Comment: I'll have a look, but only in 3 weeks

Comment: I have no problem with TeXLive 2011 and current 2012

Comment: post the file list! As I already wrote, I have no problem.

Comment: your file list shows that you dot _not_ have TL 2011 and _not_ a current TL2012. Update the PStricks files from http://texnik.dante.de

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!

`-dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress` or `-dPDFSETTINGS#/prepress` (for Windows) passed to `ps2pdf` caused the error.

Comment: No, that cannot be the problem for `\rput`

Comment: @Herbert: I have tested it and the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 5):

Actually it works for me (TL2012) if I uncomment the second one I get[image]

Comment: I used latex/dvips/ps2pdf texlive 2012 as downloaded a day or so ago