# Example from the pstricks-add manual not compiliing

Tags: pstricks-add

Consider the following example (taken from p. 29 in the [`pstricks-add` manual](http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/ctan/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pstricks-add/doc/pstricks-add-doc.pdf)):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-1,-1)(8,8)
\multido{\iA=1+1}{6}{%
  \rput(\iA,7.5){\Huge\psdice[unit=0.75,linecolor=red!80]{\iA}}
  \rput(! -0.5 7 \iA\space sub){\Huge\psdice[unit=0.75,linecolor=blue!70]{\iA
    }}%
  \multido{\iB=1+1}{6}{%
    \rput(! \iA\space 7 \iB\space sub){%
      \rnode[c]{p\iA\iB}{\makebox[1em][l]{\strut\psPrintValue[fontscale=12]{\iA
        \space \iB\space add}}}%
}}}
\ncbox[linearc=0.35,nodesep=0.2,linestyle=dotted]{p11}{p66}
\ncbox[linearc=0.35,nodesep=0.2,linestyle=dashed]{p15}{p51}
\rput{90}(-1.5,3.5){1. dice}
\rput{0}(3.5,8.5){2. dice}
\psline[linewidth=1.5pt](0.25,0.5)(0.25,8)
\psline[linewidth=1.5pt](-1,6.75)(6.5,6.75)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

I get the error

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \strut \psPrintValue 
                                [fontscale=12]{\iA \space \iB \space add}
l.16 }
```

when I compile using `latex`.

How do I make the code compile?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is as short as a comment. You need [`pst-tools`](http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/ctan/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-tools/doc/pst-tools-doc.pdf) probably. I have been using the macro in question for several decades; see [Why does \psPrintValue not allow 2 \rput to work at the same time?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63990/19356).

Comment: Bingo!  That's it.